# Ubuntu Server Very Slow Boot up

Tags: boot, server, grub2

I installed ubuntu on a PC "server" for offline development purposes but im having slow boot ups.

When i press the power button the system goes straight to the CRUB menu for about 2 seconds. But then goes to a black screen with fast moving text. This process usually takes about 5 to 10 mins.

Is there any solution to fix this problem or will i have to re-install everything ?

This is a clean install, With noting else installed yet.

Comment: did you installed `Ubuntu Desktop` or `Ubuntu Server`? Also paste the output of `systemd-analyze critical-chain`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a kernel panic (hard crash). It can come from a hardware failure... like a defective hard disk, bad RAM, or from corruption of a software component.

The first thing is to perform a file system check on your Ubuntu disk. Hopefully you can do this on the **server** version of Ubuntu...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- as soon as you see the GRUB menu, and before it crashes, hit the **down** arrow key *(you may not be able to get this far)*
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- *you can ignore errors about the time/date/superblock*
- repeat the fsck command if there were other errors
- type `reboot`

The second thing to do is to use the SMART internal disk monitoring tools to see if it detects a pending hard disk failure...

- create a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB **desktop** version
- boot to the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start the `Disks` application from the Unity dash
- select the hard disk in the left pane
- click on the "hamburger" icon in the top-right of the Disks window
- select `SMART Data & Tests`
- view the data, and run the tests